# Jade template engine / How to set a background image

Tags: html, pug

I would like to set a background-image to my HTML page rendered with [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/).
Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background image is set in the CSS of the page. And that has almost nothing to do with Jade.

So, in your page CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url(/images/img1.jpg);
}
```

Or using a class that you then assign to one of the elements in your jade template:

```
.bkimg {
    background-image: url(/images/img1.jpg);
}
```

and the jade:

```
body.bkimg
    p this is a fine body
```

The same applies for any element type.

Answer (score 14):

You can set the style attribute like this:

```
div(style='background-image: url(/myImage.jpg);')
```

However, you should avoid using inline style. Separate your content from design - keep html and css in separate files.

Read more about attributes in jade [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a6-9).

Comment: And if you are trying to set the image inside a template, it's probably for a dynamic piece of content... which might look something like this:
`div(style='background-image: url(images/' + post.img + ');')`